# How to extract all strings in require('')?

Tags: bash, regex, grep, sed, cut

My source files are something like this:

```
abl require('../img/a.png') require('../img/b.png')
bla require('../../img/c.png')
ble <Image source={require('../img/d.png')}
```

My expected output is:

```
'../img/a.png'
'../img/b.png'
'../../img/c.png'
'../img/d.png'
```

In a Bash script I need to extract all required `'../../img/bla.png'` for every line of a file. May be one line for multiple items.

I tried using this:

```
cat file | cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d')' -f1
```

But I this can only cut for one string for one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Po '(?<=require\().*?(?=\))'
```

It uses look-behind and look-ahead. It will fail if any path includes `)`. If every path is within single quotes then this version should work even with `)` in paths:

```
grep -Po "(?<=require\()'.*?'(?=\))"
```

This was tested on Linux, GNU grep. Mac users, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16658333).

Comment: Nice solution with grep and PCRE! I was trying to filter with sed, then I realized that would be more easier split in fields with awk `awk -F'[()]' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /\//) print $i};}'`

Comment: Great job. [Grep -P not work well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches), so I use `perl -nle 'print $& if m{img\/.*?.(png|jpg|mp4)}' file` done this job

Comment: @FaiChou Thank you for your feedback. I have included the link in my answer.